# Minimal Malayalam XeLaTeX document

Tags: fonts, xetex, books

I have been typesetting books in Malayalam using XeLaTeX, with the Rachana font for Malayalam and FreeSerif for English. One problem with Rachana is that it doesn't contain glyphs such as the "curly quotes" and emdash and endash. This means that I have to use these characters from Free Serif, making the code a bit more complex than needed. As a result, I have always felt that my document is more lengthy than is absolutely needed, and I have been trying to create a minimal document that would suit my needs.

With this in mind, I wrote the following document, which, to me looks correct (but clearly it is not). When I compile it, it ends with the error, "xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without the font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/malayalam-fonts/Rachana-Bold.woff

Output file removed." although the woff files for normal and bold are available on the system in their proper directory, namely, /usr/share/fonts/truetype/malayalam-fonts.

Could anyone please point to some solution to this problem?

I am using XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) on GNU/Linux Mint 4.9.0-8-amd64.
My minimal document is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2.00cm]{geometry}
\sloppy
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia,xltxtra}
\newfontfamily\malayalamfont[Script=Malayalam,Mapping=tex-text]{Rachana}
\setmainfont{Rachana}
\newfontfamily\engfont[Mapping=tex-text]{FreeSerif}
\def\xromn#1{{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont#1}}
\def\squote{\xromn{`}}
\def\esquote{\xromn{'}}
\def\dquote{\xromn{``}}
\def\edquote{\xromn{''}}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\myfont}{\engfont}
\def\mdash{\myfont{\textemdash}}
\def\ndash{\myfont{\textendash}}
\linespread{1.2}
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\raggedbottom
\sloppy

\begin{document}
\myfont{``}ഇതു് സീലാറ്റെക്കിൽ ചെയ്ത ഏറ്റവും ചെറിയ മലയാളം പുസ്തകമാണു്.\myfont{''} \ndash Language=\languagename

\textbf{മലയാളം ബോൾഡ്} \textit{മലയാളം ഫേക് ഇറ്റാലിക്}

\myfont{``This is the smallest'' Malayalam article class document\mdash  that can be made with \XeLaTeX .}
\textbf{FreeSerif Bold} \textit{FreeSerif Italic} \textsf{Sans English} Language=\languagename
\end{document}
```

Comment: woff fonts are the wrong font format. xelatex should better not see them.

Comment: Do you mean that they shouldn't exist there in that folder? Will try removing them and see if the compilation works.